# How to close the table on click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a table which takes the user details. The code is as follows:

```
<table id="record" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Emp Name</td> 
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Add">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, when I click on the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, the table should close. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'close'? Should the table just disappear from the screen but retain its data somehow, or do you want to remove the table altogether?

Comment: i think he want that table would slide up...

Comment: i wanted to close the entire table on clicking the Cancel button.

Comment: Can this be achieved in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the input button an id...

```
   <input type="button" id="close" value="cancel">
```

Then add some Jquery...(assuming you are using jquery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#close').click(function(){$('#record').hide();});

 });
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/ufCkw/3)

Or theres the one liner...

```
  <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="$('#record').hide();">
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/ufCkw/4/)

**EDIT**

And....Your request for just pure javascript...

```
<input type="button" id="close" value="Cancel" onclick=" document.getElementById('record').style.display = 'none';">
```

[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/ufCkw/2/)